# Is there a way to make render preview less fuzzy

Tags: rendering, denoise

I know how to make my final render without noise or grain. But my preview render is always grainy/noisy. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The quality for the 3d viewport (in rendered view for cycles) is determined by the number of samples for preview.

For 2.79

[image]

Or samples for Viewport in 2.8.

[image]

You can use more samples, but be aware that it will make the interface less responsive.

Do a search also for **Render Border**, where you can just render a section of the image

Comment: It might be more robust to tune light bounces setting than simply change the sample count. The default bounces amount in Blender is too good for previewing. But the setting is kind of complicated for beginner as well.